# No costmap received Nav2

Tags: ros2, rviz, ros-humble, nav2

I am trying to have my robot navigate with Nav2, I have a laptop connected to the same network as the robot in order to visualize and send navigation goals, however I am getting a "No map received" warning in RViz2 as shown below:

[image: RViz2 warning image]

I tried running the navigation nodes on the remote PC and the map shows successfully but I want to have the navigation run on the robot computer. I also tried running the SLAM on the robot and visualize on the remote PC and the map is showing as shown bellow, so I don't know what should I do to visualize the map when doing navigation.

[image]

[EDIT]

The problem with the map was that I had to configure the Durability policy to Transient local, however the costmap is still not showing, I compared the rqt_graph output on both cases (launching the navigation nodes from the robot computer and on my personal computer) and I see the `bt_navigator` node is not publishing `/bond` topic so I went to check the logs when launching navigation on the robot computer and I see there is a problem on the `bt_navigator` node when it is configuring, the error is the following:

```bash
[lifecycle_manager-12] [INFO] [1698166413.648628234] [lifecycle_manager_navigation]: Configuring bt_navigator
[bt_navigator-9] [INFO] [1698166413.648875423] [bt_navigator]: Configuring
[bt_navigator-9] [ERROR] [1698166413.694414631] []: Caught exception in callback for transition 10
[bt_navigator-9] [ERROR] [1698166413.694437451] []: Original error: Could not load library: /opt/ros/humble/lib/libnav2_compute_path_to_pose_action_bt_node.so: undefined symbol: _ZN2BT10Blackboard15createEntryImplERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERKNS_8PortInfoE
[bt_navigator-9] [WARN] [1698166413.694469440] []: Error occurred while doing error handling.
[bt_navigator-9] [FATAL] [1698166413.694478582] [bt_navigator]: Lifecycle node bt_navigator does not have error state implemented
[lifecycle_manager-12] [ERROR] [1698166413.694941267] [lifecycle_manager_navigation]: Failed to change state for node: bt_navigator
[lifecycle_manager-12] [ERROR] [1698166413.695032343] [lifecycle_manager_navigation]: Failed to bring up all requested nodes. Aborting bringup.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the map was that I had the Durability policy in RViz as Volatile instead of Transcient local. And the problem with the costmap was that I didn't installed `behaviourtree_cpp_v3` package on my robot computer.